# Using empty array members from a difflib.get_close_matches return array to store non-matched lines of a file

Tags: python, arrays, file, difflib

I am using/learning Python for the first time in an 'applied' fashion. Up until now I have been using other languages. This part of my project needs `difflib` So I may be asking this question too soon. But any suggestions at this stage would be appreciated.

Here's my code example:

```
# fileReadRightWrong.py     ---     read a file containing wrong names & correct

import difflib

# correct reference
yes = ['Summerdalerise']

# ### read text file wrong.txt line by line, without comments of course, as follows: 
# Simmerdalerise
# Winterwortslope
# Summerdolerose
# Winterdaleslope
# Summer   erise

# close matches to be stored in array result
result = []
# open file in current dir that contains the above lines of text
with open('wrong.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        result = difflib.get_close_matches(line,yes)
        # print(result) # outputs an array showing close match members at loop positions [0][2][4] eg ['Summerdalerise']

# I want to write the close match found to a new file in the correct order with the existing non-matches eg
# Summerdalerise
# Winterwortslope
# Summerdalerise
# Winterdaleslope
# Summerdalerise

# Psuedo code of what I'm trying to do
# If no value from, current loop, call to difflib. Store this line from wrong.txt file as an array member of result at this loop position. When the loop has completed:
# Write the contents of, the now full, result array, containing close matches or original lines to a new file in correct line order.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# correct reference
word = ['Summerdalerise']

# open file to store corrected list
g = open("right.txt", "a")
result = []
# open file in current dir that contains the above lines of text
with open('wrong.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        result = difflib.get_close_matches(line, word, n=1)
        if result == word:
           print(','.join(result), file=g)
        else:
           line = line.splitlines()
           print(','.join(line), file=g)
```

Output from right.txt:

```
Summerdalerise
Winterwortslope
Summerdalerise
Winterdaleslope
Summerdalerise
```